# Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed! in mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a new Hadoop user. I run this sample code from Hadoop Beginner's Guide (Garry Turkington) but I encounter a problem of job failed. I haven't see output file(part file) in my output folder.I did many changes in mapred-site.xml file but I cannot solve the problem of job failed. How should I do?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.* ;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SkipBadRecords;

public class SkipData
{
    public static class MapClass extends MapReduceBase implements   Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>
    {
        private final static LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text("totalcount");

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,     OutputCollector<Text,LongWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException
        {
            String line = value.toString();
            if (line.equals("skiptext"))
                throw new RuntimeException("Found skiptext") ;
            output.collect(word, one);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "/home/saung/hadoop-2.7.4/");
        Configuration config = new Configuration() ;
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(config, SkipData.class);
        conf.setJobName("SkipData");
        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
        conf.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);
        conf.setCombinerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(LongSumReducer.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,args[0]) ;
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1])) ;
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
    }
}
```

**mapred-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
<value>yarn</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapred.skip.map.max.skip.records</name>
<value>5</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapred.map.max.attempts</name>
<value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapred.reduce.max.attempts</name>
<value>4</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>mapreduce.max.map.failures.percent</name>
<value>20</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**input file got form this ruby file**

```
File.open('skipdata.txt','w') do |file|
3.times do
500000.times{file.write("A valid record\n")}
5.times{file.write("skiptext\n")}
end
500000.times{file.write("A valid record\n")}
end
```

**I used 8 map tasks and errors are look like this:**

```
 18/02/27 14:21:50 INFO mapred.Task: Task     'attempt_local1745706455_0001_m_000007_0' done.
18/02/27 14:21:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task:     attempt_local1745706455_0001_m_000007_0
18/02/27 14:21:50 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map task executor complete.
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (1882349076) connection to     localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from saung sending #18
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction          as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskCompletionEvents(Job.java:670)
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction  as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction  as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (1882349076) connection to      localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from naychi got value #18
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine: Call: delete took 69ms
18/02/27 14:21:50 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local1745706455_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found skiptext
at  org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:462)
at     org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:522)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Found skiptext
at mapredpack.SkipData$MapClass.map(SkipData.java:81)
at mapredpack.SkipData$MapClass.map(SkipData.java:1)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner  .java:243)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
18/02/27 14:21:50 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction  as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.getAbstractFileSystem(FileContext.java:3 31)
18/02/27 14:21:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000 /taskfailure/skipdata.txt:4194304+4194304 > map
18/02/27 14:21:51 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 69% reduce 0%
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction  as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskCompletionEvents(Job.java:670)
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction  as:saung (auth:SIMPLE)  from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:saung (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getTaskCompletionEvents(Job.java:670)
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:saung (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:saung (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.updateStatus(Job.java:320)
18/02/27 14:21:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local1745706455_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG security.UserGroupInformation: PrivilegedAction as:saung (auth:SIMPLE) from:org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.getCounters(Job.java:758)
18/02/27 14:21:51 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 23
File System Counters
    FILE: Number of bytes read=24806
    FILE: Number of bytes written=1741540
    FILE: Number of read operations=0
    FILE: Number of large read operations=0
    FILE: Number of write operations=0
    HDFS: Number of bytes read=107677710
    HDFS: Number of bytes written=0
    HDFS: Number of read operations=70
    HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
    HDFS: Number of write operations=7
Map-Reduce Framework
    Map input records=1381528
    Map output records=1381527
    Map output bytes=26249013
    Map output materialized bytes=135
    Input split bytes=588
    Combine input records=1161148
    Combine output records=5
    Spilled Records=5
    Failed Shuffles=0
    Merged Map outputs=0
    GC time elapsed (ms)=2000
    Total committed heap usage (bytes)=3535798272
File Input Format Counters 
    Bytes Read=20743175
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:873)
at mapredpack.SkipData.main(SkipData.java:100)
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping client from cache:  org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@2cd2a21f
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG ipc.Client: removing client from cache: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@2cd2a21f
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG ipc.Client: stopping actual client because no more references remain: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client@2cd2a21f
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG ipc.Client: Stopping client
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (1882349076) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from saung: closed
18/02/27 14:21:51 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (1882349076) connection to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 from saung: stopped, remaining connections 0
18/02/27 14:21:51 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: hdfs://localhost:9000/taskfailure/skipdata.txt:12582912+4194304 > map
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace

Comment: I provided with required data. How should I do to prevent failed job?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as if this expected behavior.

- You have a `Mapper` that is designed to throw an exception when it encounters a record (line) `"skiptext"`.
- Your input contains some lines of that form.
- The exception is being thrown ...
- .... and the job is failing.

I suspect that you are trying to implement bad record skipping as described in the [MapReduce Tutorial](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Skipping_Bad_Records).  However, it doesn't look like you are doing it correctly.

I can see that you have imported `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SkipBadRecords` ... but simply importing a class in Java doesn't actually do *anything*.

According to the Tutorial:

> By default this feature is disabled.
>
> For enabling it, refer to `SkipBadRecords.setMapperMaxSkipRecords(Configuration, long)` and `SkipBadRecords.setReducerMaxSkipGroups(Configuration, long)`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to add these two lines in main(), but I still have this problem. Could you give me suggestion again ?

Comment: You should read the tutorial and the javadocs for those methods so that you **understand** what you are doing.  (And reread what I wrote.  For a start, I did not suggest that you add two lines, and nor do the lines I quoted from the tutorial.)